# Getting failed id's from for all save exceptions

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, plsql, forall

I am trying to update salary of employees using forall. Whenever any error occurs while updating I need to save for which employee id error has occurred. 
But it gives following error while compiling 
Error(14,24): PLS-00201: identifier 'INDX' must be declared

Below is my code

```
PROCEDURE PROC1 (V_EMP_ID DBMS_SQL.NUMBER_TABLE)
IS
     lv_error_string VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    FORALL INDX IN V_EMP_ID.FIRST..V_EMP_ID.LAST SAVE EXCEPTIONS
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET SALARY=SALARY+10000 WHERE EMP_ID=:1'
    USING V_EMP_ID(INDX);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS 
    THEN
    FOR J IN 1 .. SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT
    LOOP
       lv_error_string:=lv_error_string
                    ||sqlerrm (-sql%bulk_exceptions(j).error_code)
                    || ' for'||V_EMP_ID(INDX);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this: The error is that in `exception block` you are trying to access a loop variable that is being used in `begin block`.

So your `|| ' for'||V_EMP_ID(INDX);` should be `|| ' for'||V_EMP_ID(J);`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC1 (V_EMP_ID DBMS_SQL.NUMBER_TABLE)
IS
     lv_error_string VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    FORALL INDX IN V_EMP_ID.FIRST..V_EMP_ID.LAST SAVE EXCEPTIONS
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET SALARY=SALARY+10000 WHERE EMP_ID=:1'
    USING V_EMP_ID(INDX);
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS 
    THEN
    FOR J IN 1 .. SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT
    LOOP
       lv_error_string:=lv_error_string
                    ||sqlerrm (-sql%bulk_exceptions(j).error_code)
                    || ' for'||V_EMP_ID(J);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Not sure why you use `Execute Immediate` when you can easily do as below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROC1 (V_EMP_ID DBMS_SQL.NUMBER_TABLE)
IS
     lv_error_string VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    FORALL INDX IN V_EMP_ID.FIRST..V_EMP_ID.LAST SAVE EXCEPTIONS
    UPDATE EMPLOYEES 
    SET SALARY=SALARY+10000 
    WHERE EMP_ID= V_EMP_ID(INDX);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS 
    THEN
    FOR J IN 1 .. SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.COUNT
    LOOP
       lv_error_string:=lv_error_string
                    ||sqlerrm (-sql%bulk_exceptions(j).error_code)
                    || ' for'||V_EMP_ID(J);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: This works but doesn't give me employee id for which error occurred@XING

Comment: So coming to your issue am not sure why are you doing a `execute immediate` when you can directly run the `update`. See my updated post. You are not getting any `employee_id` coz oracle doenot find any `exception`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go with a single DML statement. And yes DML error loggins is possible.Hope this helps

```
--Creating a error log table
BEGIN
  DBMS_ERRLOG.create_error_log (dml_table_name => 'EMPLOYEES');
END;
/
--ERR$_EMPLOYEES --> Errro table created


--Insertion with erroreous record
UPDATE EMPLOYEES
SET SALARY         = SALARY + 10000
where EMP_ID               in (<EMP_ID COLLECTION array
OR simple EMP_IDs>) LOG ERRORS
INTO ERR$_EMPLOYEES ('UPDATE') REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;

--Error will be logged into ERR$_EMPLOYEES table
```

Comment: LOG ERRORS is a great idea, but remember that it will preserve rows successfully modified within a single statement, which is very different from SAVE EXCEPTIONS (statement-level error suppression).

Comment: Yes. I have considered only row level error handling here